# How to call selector from dynamic content using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table that its generated on server-side and then I append it to the view page (client-side). So the table is not the DOM. Then I am working using [StickyTableHeaders](https://github.com/jmosbech/StickyTableHeaders) jquery plugin to add sticky header of my table. But I can't call the table class name because the table not printed on the page. 
I tried to call the selector by :

```
    var offset = $('.navbar').height();
    $(".table").stickyTableHeaders({fixedOffset: offset});
```

So, how my table class name accessible by the StickyTableHeaders function.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [$(document).ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready) and write your code in your view file like,

```
$(function(){  // document.ready shorthand
    var offset = $('.navbar').height();
    $(".table").stickyTableHeaders({fixedOffset: offset});    
});
```

Comment: if i'm not mistaken you can't get a `.height()` when you select by class name, as this returns a collection of items. you need to specify which element you want from the collection returned.

Comment: No @Sharky you can get height by a class name as it will return the height of first matched element See [jQuery.height()](http://api.jquery.com/height) (`Get the current computed height for the first element in the set of matched elements or set the height of every matched element.`)

Comment: @Rohan Kumar I have tried the code above, but still cant access the class name, its only work in DOM